# how can i parse images with cURL?

Tags: php, parsing, curl

how can I parse images on this site with cURL?

with this code I can show the whole site's html, but I need only images:

```
 $ch = curl_init('http://www.lamoda.ru/shoes/sapogi/?sitelink=leftmenu&sf=16&rdr565=1#sf=16');


  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, '1');


  $text = curl_exec($ch);


  curl_close($ch);


   if (!preg_match('/src="https?:\/\/"/', $text))
     $text = preg_replace('/src="(.*)"/', "src=\"$MY_BASE_URL\\1\"", $text);


   echo $text;
```

thank you!

I tried this:

```
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, '1');
      $text = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);


     $doc = new DOMDocument();
     @$doc->loadHTML($text->content);

    $imgs = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');

     foreach ($imgs as $img)
      {
         $imgarray[] = $img -> getAttribute('src');
      }

  return $imgarray;
```

BUT: on this site images uploaded via JS and it doesn't show images at all =((

Comment: Just use something like simple dom parser to evaluate the contents of the returned cURL page and then you can easily iterate over it like `$html = new simple_html_dom(); $html->load($curl_scraped_page, true, false);` and then foreach($html->find('img') as $img): //$img = image endforeach;` and you're done.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, no, there images uploaded via JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a DOM Parser to achieve this:

```
$ch = curl_init('URL_GOES_HERE');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, '1');
$text = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($text);

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('img') as $img) {
    echo $img->getAttribute('src');
}
```

Comment: and you have a mistake " $dom->loadHTML($text->content); "

Answer (score 0):

you can use html parse simple_html_dom:
http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm


        `// Create DOM from URL or file 

        $url = 'http://www.lamoda.ru/shoes/sapogi/?sitelink=leftmenu&sf=16&rdr565=1#sf=16';
        $html = file_get_html($url); 

        // Find all images 

        foreach($html->find('img') as $element) 

            echo $element->src;`